# Timeout on a single statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would I set a timeout on a single statement of the code? I know timeout_decorator does that for a function but I want to know for just a single line in python 3.6.

Comment: Put the single statement inside a function and decorate it...

Comment: Other than this? Any other way? And if I want to add timeout for several statements then I can't create a single function for each statement The solution that you provided is not efficient.

Comment: The question is not properly formulated, so it's to be expected. You didn't mention all the possible use cases. Post some sample cases, and the code you've written so far. For now, I'm voting to close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by creating Process. You can create a Process using the multiprocessing library and then set a timeout using join for that particular function call or statement.

For example

```
def test():
    print("Testing")

import multiprocessing
action_process=multiprocessing.Process(target=test)
action_process.start()
action_process.join(timeout=10)
process_timedout=action_process.is_alive()
action_process.terminate()

if process_timedout:
    print("Process Timedout")
else:
    print("Process executed successfully")
```